# Wordpress Plugin: Show html only on standard page and not in admin area

Tags: wordpress

I'm writing a plugin and I need to display a piece of text in the WP page, but not in the admin area. How can I do so?

I tried this in the construct:

```
add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'initPage' ) )
```

and then:

```
public function initPage() {
      echo 'hello';            
}
```

but the text is displayed also in the admin area. Is there a way to do this? It would be the opposite of the action `admin_init` I assume.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by adding it to a shortcode action. Like this:

```
add_shortcode( 'myPlugin', array( $this, 'shortcode' ) );
```

and:

```
public function shortcode( $atts ) {
  return 'hello';
}
```

With the above code, 'hello' will only display on the front-end. Not sure if that's the cleaner way to do it, but does the job.

Comment: [Shortcodes should return their output as text](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode), so instead of `echo` you should have `return` -- e.g. `return 'hello';`

Answer (score 1):

Proper way to handle it:  is_admin()

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_admin

```
if(is_admin()) { // do nothing } else {

// function you want to execute.

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no "front-end-only" version of init, however you probably don't want to be doing any output at the init action anyway.

What exactly are you trying to do? Usually, you use an action hook for specific types of things, and causing output very early at something like "init" is rare and weird.

Comment: The idea of the plugin is to show a piece of html, more exactly a page layer. But I do not want this page layer to show on the admin area, only on the front-end part of the website.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What is a "page layer"? See, if you output at init, then your text comes before any of the actual HTML of the page generated by the theme.